# Knowing existing functions/modules etc

Tags: python

Newbie Python Learner here,
A question for programmers,
English is not main language, will be hard to explain the question I wish to convey.

How do you programmers know which modules exist and which don't?

Say you are writing a script/program etc.
There are modules/functions etc. which you may need to create or use to either write your program, or perhaps complete it quicker, how will you know a required module/function etc. exists that may help you write your program? What prevents you from wasting your time in writing an entire module/function etc. which you might need to use which may already exist without you knowing so?

Comment: What if the internet did not have the answer to that specific module/function etc. you are looking for? Or what if i am not versed well enough in the English language to properly describe the module/function etc. which i need? This also introduces an optional question i wish to ask, how did pre-internet era programmers deal with such an issue? Ty for reply btw.

Comment: Well, if you do not find anything on Google, SO, etc. after X seconds/minutes/hours, _then_ you write it yourself. The correct value of X depends on the expected complexity of writing the function yourself.

Comment: "What prevents you from wasting your time in writing an entire module/function etc. ..." if you are a new programmer, time spent in implementing such things on your own is not time *wasted*. For example, there is no better way to understand neural networks than by actually implementing one and getting your hands dirty with the back-propogation algorithm. But, if you wanted to seriously use neural nets, you would probably want to use one of the well-maintained optimized libraries for them.

Comment: Did not mean "wasting your time" in a negative way, I mean what if the situation calls for utmost efficiency, a workplace setting perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to find Python packages, in general, that can help you, usually a quick Google search or few will show you packages other people have used for similar problems as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Experience is the short answer for this.

A more detailed explanation is understanding the scope of your needs. If you believe that the problem you are faced with is a common one, chances are that someone has come up with a solution for it and put it into a module. You become aware of modules by running into a challenge and then searching up how others have solved it. You will most likely run into others who have come across the same thing and have used others modules to solve it.

The more specific your problem is the less likely there will be a module already made for it. For example, plotting data is a widely common need, which is why the Matplotlib module is known by most python programmers. Searching the PyPi website will show you a lot of modules that can come in handy later.

Good Luck and have fun looking at all the oddly specific modules out there!

Comment: You seem to me an experienced person in this field,  i hope you don't mind if i ask, if its not too much a burden, can leave blank if it is, but have you faced a similar situation during your early years programming?If so, how did you deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The main sources of info are

- docs.python.org (The Tutorial also introduces important modules in the standard lib)
- pypi.org
- StackOverflow (of course)
- Google

You can be almost sure that basic functionalities are provided by standard lib, pypi.org allows then to search by several criteria.